# ASP.NET core Cors policy

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm having problem setting up Cors policy in my ASP.NET core project.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
            builder =>
            {
                builder
                .AllowAnyOrigin() 
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials();
            });
    });
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        services.AddMemoryCache();
}
```

I've tried adding `app.UseCors("AllowAll");` in `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)`, tried `[EnableCors("AllowAll")]`before controller declaration:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[EnableCors("AllowAll")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
```

and before method declaration:

```
[HttpPost]
[EnableCors("AllowAll")]
public JsonResult Post([FromBody] dynamic request)
```

and no luck, I'm keep getting "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at..."

Maybe someone can help me?

Comment: In your Startup.cs Configure method try putting   app.UseCors("AllowAll"); after app.UseMvc();

Comment: not helped, same "Cross-Origin Request Blocked"

Comment: I have posted a sample code, you can have a look if it works

Answer (score 1):

I know this is too late, but can help someone,

using CorsMiddleware in specified order is matters

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors("AllowAll");
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseResponseCaching();
```

1. The call to UseCors must be placed after UseRouting, but before
   UseAuthorization.
2. When using Response Caching Middleware, call
   UseCors before UseResponseCaching